# Using cursor fetch specified field into local variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

A part of my procedure as below:

```sql
BEGIN
  DECLARE parentId VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE temp CURSOR FOR SELECT id,name,parent_id,parent_name,
                           FROM table;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT found SET done=1;
  SET @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 10;

  OPEN temp;

  FETCH temp.parent_id INTO parentId;

  CLOSE C_org;
END
```

temp includes multiple field,but I want to fetch specified field into a local variable, such as "temp.parent_id", but mysql will report syntax error, I can not find the anwser about that.

Comment: is anybody can help?

Comment: Either change the select to only select parent_id or change the fetch to select into 4 local variables.